# Drop-down list - exclude values in default selection - Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Drop-down list that includes hundreds of values. I want the default view to exclude single or multiple values. However, I do not wish to write all the 99 values to the Default selection to exclude one value.

I tried writing **Exclude value_1** as is written in the dropdown when you manually exclude a single value, but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same issue and didn't find the setting that would allow me to do it inside the Looker. The workaround is to exit the Edit mode, choose the necessary selections and save the current view by clicking **Share** > **Get Report Link** with selected "Link to your current report view". In this case you will get a link with the predefined selections that you can open yourself or share with anybody.

Hope it helps.